# php simple dom parser, find links with no heading as parent

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

perhaps my approach is not correct, all advice appreciated
i am trying to scrape all a tags from a web page and order then as follows
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a (all the rest)
my code so far,

```
$layout['h1']=$html->find('h1 a');
$layout['h2']=$html->find('h2 a');
$layout['h3']=$html->find('h3 a');
$layout['h4']=$html->find('h4 a');
$layout['h5']=$html->find('h5 a');
$layout['h6']=$html->find('h6 a');
$layout['a']=$html->find('a');

//then i can print the arrays as follows
foreach ($layout as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($layout[$key] as $text) {
       echo $text.' |  ';
    }
}
```

this all works well when outputting however my question is how can i get the  tags that do not have a heading tag wrapped around them.

could i for example just get all the a tags with
    $layout[all_links]= $html->find('a')
and then do a loop to remove all tags that are wrapped with  heading tag and keep whats left over. I am not sure how to code this, perhaps unset?

thanks in advance, i have tried to think of many ways to do it but at a loss, does anyone have a better suggestion or should  i re think the entire function

Comment: look at your syntax highlighted code, it looks quite strange right? you have a bunch of errors there dude

Comment: @Joshua: I fixed that for him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
  if(!preg_match('/h[1-6]/', $a->parent->tag)) echo $a;
}
```

That will skip the `a`'s whose parent is not a `h1`..`h6`

Comment: Although the question asks for _parent_, I’m not sure if not actually _ancestor_ might be what was actually meant – at least the selector `hN a` does not require the headlines to be the _parent_ of the links. And with that, just looking at the parent node would fail.

Comment: @CBroe - I didn't understand a word of that :) For ancestors you would need to throw in a while loop.

Comment: ok this approach works as long as the H[*] is the parent. i guess i need to re-think, some coders use <a><h2>... rather than <h2><a>..., thank you kindly for the replies - a great help